# Spilt a Python file into multiple files

Tags: python

Is there any module or built-in function to split a Python file containing multiple functions into multiple files each containing one function. For example, starting with:

**test.py**

```
from datetime import date
import math

def f1():
   print math.factorial(4)

def f2():
   print date.today()
```

The result should be two files:

**f1.py**

```
import math

def f1():
   print math.factorial(4)
```

**f2.py**

```
from datetime import date

def f2():
   print date.today()
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: That would be pretty difficult to automate because it would have to figure out which imports are required by which functions (the trivial way would be to include all of them in all output files, I suppose, but that's not what you show) - especially if wildcards are involved. One function per file seems a bit unnnecessary, though.

Comment: For better analysis cause the one in which I'm currently working has became too lengthy to scroll up and down.

Comment: There's no such module. You'll have to do it manually but you'll probably get stuck as this is not an easy task

Comment: Then you should split it out into files of *related* functions, not just one-function-per-file - and that's something even harder to automate!

Comment: Its not necessary that their should be one function but for the sake of analysis one if one lengthy file is divided into many chunks along with their dependencies it will increase the readability and analysis of the code will become more easier.

Comment: Yes, this is true - but, again, this is not a trivial task to automate and is a useful skill for *you* to develop. Identifying related functions and factoring them out into a separate module is best done by the developer.

Comment: Lets suppose a condition where code is written by some one else and some one else is now working on that without having access to that person then he'll have to go through a hectic and tedious task of reading entire code but if any such module can be designed then it'll save a lot of time especially in cases where projects are handed over from one employee to other.

Comment: If you think it would be useful, then start writing it, that's fair enough. However, asking for off-site resources like packages to do it is off-topic here, as is asking for help to write it (beyond solving specific implementation problems). Start with the simple version that includes all imports, then try to improve it from there.

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe I posted it cause it became requirement of my own project but just popped in my mind that if their could be or their is any existing package it'll help me a lot. Any suggestions on you're last comment **what should be the approach for such package**

Comment: @PrashantShukla again, that's too broad for SO.

Comment: any-ways thanks for time and suggestions.

Comment: I think something like this comes very near to human skills - too close in my opinion. In the end *we* would have no work. Hope that that won't happen in our livetime. ;-)